# How to run scala repl with java 11?

Tags: java, scala

I've installed java 11 on my ubuntu 20.04;

The java version:

```sh
$ java -version
penjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The scala version:

```sh
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.12 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL
```

When i try to run the scala repl i got the error:

```sh
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.8).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/Compilable
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.createInterpreter(ILoop.scala:118)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ILoop.scala:971)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ILoop.scala:971)

scala>  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReader(ILoop.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:970)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:990)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:891)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:891)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:891)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
[ERROR] Failed to disable litteral next character
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:328)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:495)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.waitAndCapture(TerminalLineSettings.java:339)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.exec(TerminalLineSettings.java:311)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.stty(TerminalLineSettings.java:282)
    at jline.internal.TerminalLineSettings.undef(TerminalLineSettings.java:158)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.disableLitteralNextCharacter(UnixTerminal.java:194)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2450)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2373)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2361)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.readOneLine(JLineReader.scala:59)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader$class.readLine(InteractiveReader.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.readLine(JLineReader.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.SplashReader.readLine(InteractiveReader.scala:142)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.SplashLoop.run(InteractiveReader.scala:71)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

If i try to run using java8 (changing the version using `update-alternatives --config java`) it works:

Repl:

```sh
$ scala
cat: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/release: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_265).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

How can i get scala repl to work along java 11? i've also changed the `JAVA_HOME` on my `.zshrc` file everytime i change between java8 and 11.

Comment: Uhm it seems your **Scala** version [should support](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html) **Java 11**, so this seems like a bug that you may report. - However, do you really need to use such an old version? Can you upgrade to `2.13` or at least `2.12`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez the project that i'm working on demands the version `2.11`

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207408/scala-epfl-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-scri ?

Comment: i don't think so @SethTisue, on my question i said that i change my java version to java8 and it works, it means that i've also changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Answer (score 4):

Scala 2.11.12 should be compatible with JDK 11 according to [Version compatibility table](https://github.com/scala/docs.scala-lang/blob/20651f5d0ecc8c16dcca1edac5cde4b745755cfc/_overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.md#L13)

```
## Version compatibility table

| JDK version | Minimum Scala versions           | Recommended Scala versions                                 |
|:-----------:|:---------------------------------|:-----------------------------------------------------------|
| 13, 14      | 2.13.2, 2.12.11                  | 2.13.3, 2.12.12                                            |
| 12          | 2.13.1, 2.12.9                   | 2.13.3, 2.12.12                                            |
| 11          | 2.13.0, 2.12.4, 2.11.12          | 2.13.3, 2.12.12, 2.11.12                                   |
| 8           | 2.13.0, 2.12.0, 2.11.0, 2.10.2   | 2.13.3, 2.12.12, 2.11.12, 2.10.7                           |
| 6, 7        | 2.11.0, 2.10.0                   | 2.11.12, 2.10.7                                            |
```

On my machine executing

```
scala --scala-version 2.11.12 -C--jvm=11
```

with [scala-runners](https://github.com/dwijnand/scala-runners) gives no error

```
➜  ~ scala --scala-version 2.11.12 -C--jvm=11
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.7).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> sys.props("java.specification.version")
res0: String = 11

scala> util.Properties.versionString
res1: String = version 2.11.12

scala>
```

Note the `-C--jvm=11` argument specifies JDK version which is downloaded by [coursier](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cli-java.html#managed-jvm-directory).