# Scala file compiles but won't run as script on Scala 2.11.12 and JDK 11

Tags: scala

The man page for `scala` says it should be able to run either a "A top-level object or a script file," but I can't get the latter to work.

```sh
# This works:
scalac Example.scala && scala Example
# ...but this doesn't:
scala Example.scala
```

The error message is always

> error: Compile server encountered fatal condition: javax/tools/DiagnosticListener
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.tools.DiagnosticListener

...but the code is simply:

```scala
object Exmple {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    System.out.println("Example")
  }
}
```

Comment: Which is your **Scala** version? Which is your **Java** version? How did you install them?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez My scala is `Scala 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.10)`; my Java is `openjdk 11.0.10 2021-01-19`; I installed them with `apt` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @JellicleCat try with JDK 8 - Scala not alway friendly with 8+ JDK's

Comment: @JellicleCat I would recommend you to use [**coursier**](https://get-coursier.io/) to install both **Java** as well as **Scala**. **apt** is not really a reliable way to install anything.

Comment: Also, btw use `println` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: Does `scala -nobootcp -nc Example.scala` work? https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10603#issuecomment-343357122

Comment: Thanks, @MarioGalic , it does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using Scala 2.11.12 and JDK 11 you might be experiencing issue [Could not launch Scala 2.10.7, 2.11.12 REPL with Java 11 (without `-nobootcp -nc` workaround) #10603](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10603) for which the workaround is

```
scala -nobootcp -nc Example.scala
```

As an alternative to installing Scala with apt in Linux consider [One-click install for Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/2020/06/29/one-click-install.html) via [coursier](https://alexarchambault.github.io/posts/2020-09-21-cs-setup.html#setup-command)

```
curl -fLo cs https://git.io/coursier-cli-"$(uname | tr LD ld)"
chmod +x cs
./cs setup
rm -f cs
```

which should install all the necessary components for Scala development.

Related answer that mentions scala-runners: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64231391/5205022